# How do I programatically show the DropDown of ContextMenuStrip?

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenustrip

I need a button to show the ContextMenuStrip associated with it on mouse left click instead of right click. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below

```
Point location = button1.PointToScreen(Point.Empty);
contextMenuStrip1.Show(location);
```

PointToScreen gets the actual location of your button and shows the context menu strip where the button located.

Answer (score 0):

If `cmenEdit` is your `ContextMenu` and `btnEdit` is your button, in your `BtnEdit_Click` event you will have this:

```
cmenEdit.Show(btnEdit, new Point(0, btnEdit.Height));
```

ContextMenu will show under the button, and will look like this (as an example)

[image: img]